# How to convert tuple of lists to only tuple?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

How can I convert

```
([1,2,3],[4,5])
```

to

```
(1,2,3,4,5)
```

in Python?

I just want to convert the lists in the tuple to a single tuple, it means to remove the list.

Answer (score 1):

```
tpl = ([1,2,3],[4,5])

print(tuple(sum(tpl, [])))
```

Prints:

```
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

OR:

Using `itertools.chain`:

```
from itertools import chain

print(tuple(chain.from_iterable(tpl)))
```

OR:

Using comprehensions:

```
print(tuple(i for lst in tpl for i in lst))
```

Comment: I try it and  get correct answer I want ,thanks~